# Stopping a Fabric Task From Running

Tags: python, fabric

The method I currently use if one fabric task fails on one of my servers is

to

```
try:
   sudo(...)
except SystemExit():
   raise Exception("You should fix this with...")
```

However, this leaves an unpleasant stack trace from the exception when all I want to do is print the message from the exception. However, if I don't throw this exception then the fabric script will continue to run on my other servers when I want it to stop.

Is there a way to stop all fabric tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to stop execution of script on all servers with log message, but no stacktrace. You can do it with:

```
import sys
try:
    sudo(...)
except SystemExit():
    print "You should fix this with..." # you can use logging here
    sys.exit()
```